# offset().top returning window object

Tags: jquery

i can't get this through.

I need to get offset().top from a jquery object, this is my code

```
parentLi = $(element).parents("li");
parentLiOffset = parentLi.offset();
top = parentLiOffset.top;
left = parentLiOffset.left;
console.log(parentLiOffset);
console.log(top);
console.log(left);
```

And this is what console gives back:

```
Object { top=208, left=311}  
Window /demo/
311
```

as you can see, I can't manage to get the "top" value. I'm usinf firefox, if that makes any difference.

Thanks!

Comment: As a side-note: Do this instead: `var parentLi = $( element ).closest( 'li' );`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't used the `var` keyword to declare your variables. [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top) is a property of `window` (a read-only property, which is why your code doesn't overwrite it). Do this instead:

```
var top = parentLiOffset.top;
var left = parentLiOffset.left;
```

`left` works without `var`, because `left` is not a property of `window`. Your code creates a property of `window` named `left` and assigns the correct value to it. However, it is good practice to always use the `var` keyword to prevent variables leaking into the global scope.

The `top` property "returns a reference to the topmost window in the window hierarchy".

Comment: I knew it was something like this...
Thanks a lot! That was fast and accurate!

Comment: Man, you just saved me hours.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare those variables locally.

Do this:

```
var top = ...
var left = ...
```

When you don't declare variables beforehand, they are treated as global properties. In this case, you're trying to write to the `window.top` property which is read-only.

Failing to declare variables beforehand is dangerous since it can produce unexpected results (as you saw for yourself).

Answer (score 1):

Is that the only code or have you got something betwin your definition of `top` and the consol.log.

And yes, it is a good thing getting used to writting "var" before your variable when you declare them.